# error while destructor called

Tags: c++, c++11, heap-memory

I have a class that has two field one of them is a pointer and another is int value to hold length of string sets in constructor.

```
class MyString 
{
    char* m_pchString;
    int m_nLength;
public:
    MyString(const char* pchString="")
    {

        m_nLength = strlen(pchString) + 1;
        m_pchString = new char(m_nLength);
        strcpy_s(m_pchString,m_nLength, pchString);
    }

    MyString(const MyString &Source)
    {
        m_nLength = Source.m_nLength;
        if (Source.m_pchString)
        {
            m_pchString = new char(m_nLength);
            strcpy_s(m_pchString,m_nLength,Source.m_pchString); 
        }
        else
        {
            m_pchString = 0;
        }
    }

    ~MyString() 
    {
        delete[] m_pchString;
        m_pchString = 0;
    }

    char* GetString()
    {
        return m_pchString;
    }

    int GetLength()
    {
        return m_nLength;
    }
};
```

Then use it in console application and create an object cHello .afterward create another object an assign it by cHello within a block

```
int main()
{
    MyString cHello ("Hello,World");
    {
        MyString cCopy = cHello;
    }

    std::cout << cHello.GetString();
}
```

When the lifetime of cCopy ends, the destructor of cCopy gives me an error. What is the problem in this code?

Comment: You're missing a user defined copy-assignment operator. If you ever write `MyString str; ...; str = someOtherString;`, you'll create a shallow copy that will share the `char*` pointer and delete it early. See the [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Why are you using C "strings" and not `std::string`?

Answer (score 3):

The expression `m_pchString = new char(m_nLength)` allocates *one* character, and initializes it to the value `m_nLength`. It does *not* allocate an array of `m_nLength` elements.

That means you will go way out of bounds when copying the string into the memory pointed to by `m_pchString`, and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to allocate an array or more than one elements you need to use square brackets `[]`, as in

```
m_pchString = new char[m_nLength];
```